# Unable to parse JSON to Android

Tags: android, json

I am trying to parse some JSON from a URL in android. The JSON looks like the following:

```
[{"ID":6,"Username":"heather","Guide":false},{"ID":7,"Username":"heather","Guide":false},{"ID":9,"Username":"heather","Guide":false},{"ID":11,"Username":"heather","Guide":false}]
```

I can get the JSON Object. But then I am struggling to turn it into a JSONArray because there are no values for the JSONArray parameter.

I have tried:

```
reader = new JSONObject(result);
jsonArray = reader.getJSONArray("");
```

as well as

```
reader = new JSONObject(result);
jsonArray = reader.getJSONArray();
```

And I am not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top level is an array, so you should call `new JSONArray(result)` instead of JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

Try this this might work use JSONArray instead of JSON Object.
Square braces means array
Curly braces means object.

```
reader = new JSONArray(result);
for(int i=0;i<reader.length;i++){
jsonObject = reader.getJSONObject(i);
}
```